# Semver: Can a function be removed without a major version bump?

Tags: semantic-versioning

When using semantic versioning, can a function be removed from a project without a major version bump if that function isn't intended to be part of the public API?

Ref: http://semver.org/

Answer (score 2):

Major version increment comes when you make incompatible API changes. If your function do not affect the API, then you shouldn't go for it.

Answer (score 1):

If the function was ever a part of the public API, intentionally or not, then removing it is a breaking change and thus a major version increment.